# SVG Wave animation at the bottom of a video background hero

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I have a hero section on my webpage that I would like to create an animated wave animation at the bottom. The hero section displays a video background.

I have the video background working, and the animated waves, however, I am stuck with having a straight blue border between the two, as shown in the picture.

[image]

I can use a negative margin to bring the waves up on top of the video background but you end up with a hard border still.

It may be the way I have implemented the SVG but I'm a little lost now.

For sake of brevity, I have removed some elements (buttons, as this makes no difference) This is the HTML.

```
<div class="newHero">
  <h2>Using Sail Training to Inspire & Change Lives</h2>
  <p>Morvargh Sailing Project is a youth development organisation that helps young people become more confident, more resilient, more motivated and better able to communicate though volunteer led, life-changing sail training voyages.</p>
  <a href="tel:xxxx" class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="fa-solid fa-phone-volume"></i>Contact Us</a>
  <video class="video-bg" autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="frontend/vid/MSP.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
  </video>
</div>
<div class="waves">
  <svg class="waves" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 24 150 28 " preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <defs>
      <path id="wave-path" d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z">
    </defs>
    <g class="wave1">
      <use xlink:href="#wave-path" x="50" y="3" fill="rgba(255,255,255, .1)">
    </g>
    <g class="wave2">
      <use xlink:href="#wave-path" x="50" y="0" fill="rgba(255,255,255, .2)">
    </g>
    <g class="wave3">
      <use xlink:href="#wave-path" x="50" y="9" fill="#fff">
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

This is the CSS

```
<style>
.newHero {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(46, 59, 78,1), rgba(255, 64, 64,0.3));
  /*background: rgba(46, 59, 78, 0.85);*/
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 70vh;
}
.newHero h2 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 550px;
}
.newHero p {
  max-width: 550px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.newHero a {
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-left: 25px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-weight: 600;
}

.newHero a:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}   

.newHero i {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-size: 32px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.video-bg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.waves {
  background: rgba(46, 59, 78, 0.75);
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.wave1 use {
  -webkit-animation: move-forever1 10s linear infinite;
  animation: move-forever1 10s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

.wave2 use {
  -webkit-animation: move-forever2 8s linear infinite;
  animation: move-forever2 8s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

.wave3 use {
  -webkit-animation: move-forever3 6s linear infinite;
  animation: move-forever3 6s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move-forever1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }
}

@keyframes move-forever1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move-forever2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }
}

@keyframes move-forever2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move-forever3 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }
}

@keyframes move-forever3 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }
}

</style>
```

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to make the wave animation without a hard border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `.waves` has a background-color you need to remove. Then you can use a negative margin in order to pull the waves up. I also added `position:relative` to `.waves` so it applies the `z-index`.

```css
.newHero {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(46, 59, 78,1), rgba(255, 64, 64,0.3));
  /*background: rgba(46, 59, 78, 0.85);*/
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 70vh;
}
.newHero h2 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 550px;
}
.newHero p {
  max-width: 550px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.newHero a {
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-left: 25px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-weight: 600;
}

.newHero a:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}   

.newHero i {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-size: 32px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.video-bg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.waves {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -30px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

.wave1 use {
  -webkit-animation: move-forever1 10s linear infinite;
  animation: move-forever1 10s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

.wave2 use {
  -webkit-animation: move-forever2 8s linear infinite;
  animation: move-forever2 8s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

.wave3 use {
  -webkit-animation: move-forever3 6s linear infinite;
  animation: move-forever3 6s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move-forever1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }
}

@keyframes move-forever1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move-forever2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }
}

@keyframes move-forever2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move-forever3 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }
}

@keyframes move-forever3 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="newHero">
  <h2>Using Sail Training to Inspire & Change Lives</h2>
  <p>Morvargh Sailing Project is a youth development organisation that helps young people become more confident, more resilient, more motivated and better able to communicate though volunteer led, life-changing sail training voyages.</p>
  <a href="tel:xxxx" class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="fa-solid fa-phone-volume"></i>Contact Us</a>
  <video class="video-bg" autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="frontend/vid/MSP.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
  </video>
</div>
<div class="waves">
  <svg class="waves" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 24 150 28 " preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <defs>
      <path id="wave-path" d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z">
    </defs>
    <g class="wave1">
      <use xlink:href="#wave-path" x="50" y="3" fill="rgba(255,255,255, .1)">
    </g>
    <g class="wave2">
      <use xlink:href="#wave-path" x="50" y="0" fill="rgba(255,255,255, .2)">
    </g>
    <g class="wave3">
      <use xlink:href="#wave-path" x="50" y="9" fill="#fff">
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```